# How to mock a web server for unit testing in Java?

Tags: java, junit

I would like to create a unit test using a mock web server.  Is there a web server written in Java which can be easily started and stopped from a JUnit test case?

Comment: Task looks more like creating integration test, not a unit test.

Comment: If you read "unit test" as test technology ("JUnit") and quality (fast, no prerequisites, test cases isolated), rather than a size (testing only one unit), then an "integration test" can be a "unit test".

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed as not meeting SO guidelines. It seems perfectly clear to me what the OP is asking here. Are we splitting hairs about whether this would be a unit or integration test and whether a real web server spun up for test purposes can be considered a mock?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [Simple](http://www.simpleframework.org)([Maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.simpleframework%22%20a%3A%22simple%22)) its very easy to embed in a unit test. Take the RoundTripTest and examples such as the [PostTest](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/simpleweb/svn/trunk/simple-test/src/test/java/org/simpleframework/http/validate/test/PostTest.java) written with Simple. Provides an example of how to embed the server into your test case.

Also Simple is much lighter and faster than Jetty, with no dependencies. So you won't have to add several jar files onto your classpath. Nor will you have to be concerned with `WEB-INF/web.xml` or any other artifacts.

Comment: While it is probably what the user wanted, this isn't a "mock" web server it is an actual web server that is launched within the unit test. For example, if the port was taken it would fail, so not a true mock (ie does have an external dependency from the system). According to Martin Fowler's nomenclature fore ["Test Doubles"](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html), this is a "fake". That said, it was **exactly** what I was looking for.

Comment: Did this project go defunct?

Answer (score 49):

[Wire Mock](http://wiremock.org/index.html) seems to offer a solid set of stubs and mocks for testing external web services.

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8089);


@Test
public void exactUrlOnly() {
    stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/some/thing"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                .withBody("Hello world!")));

    assertThat(testClient.get("/some/thing").statusCode(), is(200));
    assertThat(testClient.get("/some/thing/else").statusCode(), is(404));
}
```

It can integrate with spock as well. Example found [here](https://allegro.tech/2015/07/testing-server-faults-with-Wiremock.html).

Comment: This worked very well  for me. Using wireMockConfig().dynamicPort() makes it more predictable in a setting where other programs might use the port. I wish it was the default as I almost missed this possibility and skipped this great library.

Comment: @gribo I suppose testClient is your actual instance under test.

Answer (score 21):

You can write a mock with the JDK's `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` class as well (no external dependencies required).  See [this blog post](https://alistairisrael.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/functional-http-testing-with-sun-java-6-httpserver/) detailing how.

In summary:

```
HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0); // or use InetSocketAddress(0) for ephemeral port
httpServer.createContext("/api/endpoint", new HttpHandler() {
   public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
      byte[] response = "{\"success\": true}".getBytes();
      exchange.sendResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, response.length);
      exchange.getResponseBody().write(response);
      exchange.close();
   }
});
httpServer.start();

try {
// Do your work...
} finally {
   httpServer.stop(0); // or put this in an @After method or the like
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to assert if the `HttpServer` received a request?

Comment: The  com.sun.* classes shouldn't be used.

Comment: @RamPatra you can track it within your Handler class (what they requested, etc.)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr com.sun.* is ok. It is "sun.*" or "jdk.internal.*" shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 20):

Are you trying to use a [*mock* or an *embedded*](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) web server?

For a *mock* web server, try using [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito), or something similar, and just mock the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects like:

```
MyServlet servlet = new MyServlet();
HttpServletRequest mockRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
HttpServletResponse mockResponse = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter printOut = new PrintWriter(out);
when(mockResponse.getWriter()).thenReturn(printOut);

servlet.doGet(mockRequest, mockResponse);

verify(mockResponse).setStatus(200);
assertEquals("my content", out.toString());
```

For an *embedded* web server, you could use [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), which you can [use in tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593016/run-jettys-servlettester-within-junit-test).

Answer (score 8):

Another good alternative would be [MockServer](http://www.mock-server.com/); it provides a fluent interface with which you can define the behaviour of the mocked web server.

Comment: Also the MockServer depends on Netty (not Jetty).

Answer (score 7):

You can try [Jadler](https://github.com/jadler-mocking/jadler/wiki) which is a library with a fluent programmatic Java API to stub and mock http resources in your tests. Example:

```
onRequest()
    .havingMethodEqualTo("GET")
    .havingPathEqualTo("/accounts/1")
    .havingBody(isEmptyOrNullString())
    .havingHeaderEqualTo("Accept", "application/json")
.respond()
    .withDelay(2, SECONDS)
    .withStatus(200)
    .withBody("{\\"account\\":{\\"id\\" : 1}}")
    .withEncoding(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
    .withContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: I tried using Jadler but whenever I am trying to call `initJadler()` I am getting the error as mentioned https://github.com/jadler-mocking/jadler/issues/107 . Any thoughts what could be going wrong?

Comment: Could you please paste a result of mvn dependency:tree here? It may be a clash of libraries.

Comment: Please read my answer in github.com/jadler-mocking/jadler/issues/107 , the problem is caused by clash of Jetty versions (8 vs 9). You can either remove the Jetty9 dependency (if it's not needed for the test run) or run Jadler without the Jetty dependency (https://github.com/jadler-mocking/jadler/wiki/Using-the-Alternative-Stub-Server-Implementation)

Comment: Looks like TestNG is not supported for this framework see https://github.com/jadler-mocking/jadler/issues/118

Comment: The bug report was closed as irreproducible. You can definitely use Jadler together with TestNG.

Comment: @JanDudek - Would you still recommend Jadler today or something else ? Btw, the last commit for Jadler was in early 2017. Is the project being maintained actively ? I would like my mock api to respond after certain time, or after certain number of retries etc. Can Jadler or another library do that for me ?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using apache HttpClient, This will be a good alternative. 
[HttpClientMock](https://github.com/PawelAdamski/HttpClientMock)

```java
HttpClientMock httpClientMock = new httpClientMock() 
HttpClientMock("http://example.com:8080"); 
httpClientMock.onGet("/login?user=john").doReturnJSON("{permission:1}");
```

Basically, you then make requests on your mock object and then can do some verifies on it `httpClientMock.verify().get("http://localhost/login").withParameter("user","john").called()`

Comment: Can HttpClientMock return a correct response with a delay, or only after a few number of retries ? How does this compare to Jadler https://stackoverflow.com/a/34955472/6648326 ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [Jetty web server](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

Comment: could you please give an example code like the one given for Jadler over here -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34955472/6648326 ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Javalin](https://javalin.io/). It's an excellent tool for mocking the real service as it allows for state assertions in your tests (server side assertions).

[Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) can be used as well. But it leads to hard to maintain behavioral tests (verify that client calls are as expected).

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of completeness there is also wrapping jetty with [camel](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jetty-component.html) to make it slightly more user friendly.

make your test class extend `CamelTestSupport` then define a route ex:

```
  @Override
  protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() {
        from("jetty:http://localhost:" + portToUse).process(
                new Processor() {
                  @Override
                  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    // Get the request information.
                    requestReceivedByServer = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH);

                    // For testing empty response
                    exchange.getOut().setBody("your response");
                    ....
```

example maven dependencies to get it:

```
<dependency> <!-- used at runtime, by camel in the tests -->
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```