# Where is the Jetty ServletTester class packaged?

Tags: java, maven, jar, gradle, jetty

I am trying to follow [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593016/run-jettys-servlettester-within-junit-test) which uses a Jetty [`ServletTester`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/7.6.16.v20140903/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/testing/ServletTester.html) class.

I have spent all morning trying to locate the JAR that houses `ServletTester` to no avail. Even pulling down the aggregated "`all` JAR" doesn't turn up a `*.testing` package with that class in it. See for yourself, do a Maven/Gradle resolve for:

```
compile 'org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server:8.1.14.v20131031'
```

Even in their source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project) it looks like there isn't a `testing` subproject, yet, in those JavaDocs above, it seems to exists *somewhere*...

Does anybody know where I can find the JAR that houses this class? If so, what is it, where/how do I acquire this JAR, and what did you do to figure this out (so I don't need to ask these types of questions again!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Maven Central, this class can be found in `org.eclipse.jetty:test-jetty-servlet:8.1.16.v20140903:jar`

Add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, you can use sites like [Maven Central's](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav) find artifact by class name feature.