# I have problem how to make jUnit tests for consume REST api method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I need to make JUnit/Mockito tests for that code but I don't have an idea how to start it. I couldn't find an answer or any help in SO so I made a new topic. Could someone write an example of how I should do this?

```java
 @Override
    public List<CurrencyList> currencyValuesNBP() {
        ArrayList<CurrencyList> currencyListArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A?format=json");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String jsonOutput = bufferedReader.readLine();

            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            currencyListArrayList = objectMapper.readValue(jsonOutput, new TypeReference<ArrayList<CurrencyList>>() {
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return currencyListArrayList;
    }
```

Comment: what your test should check exactly about this method?

Comment: keep in mind that you would need to refactor this method quite a bit in order to be able to isolate behavior for a unit tetst

Comment: Never actually wrote these kinds of junit tests, but it seems to me you might want to add some boiler plate code for raising a simple test server which will provide you with data for the URL being used by you method. From then on things should be straight forward IMHO. Also - it seems like a rather rigid implementation - would you not rather have a base method which, given a URL, returns a base object, and use this method for specific URLs and their specific returned objects?

Comment: You can create a mock server using WireMock, there's no need to create an actual server for a unit test.
See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606352/how-to-mock-a-web-server-for-unit-testing-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest 2 approaches to testing your method:

1. Using a dedicated testing server - In your JUnit class, create an instance of a server which will return a fixed object when receiving the URL your method uses ('http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A?format=json'). You can use a mock server such as [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/), as mentioned by `ionut`. After setting up the server, you can invoke your tested method and perform the required checks on its return values. The cons of this approach - needing to create a server and having to change the unit test code if the URL is changed in the method implementation.
2. Refactoring your method to a core method and a specific usage method, and testing the core method - refactor your code to the following:

`@Override
public List<CurrencyList> currencyValuesNBP() {
       List<CurrencyList> currencyListArrayList = new ArrayList<>();`

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A?format=json");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        currencyListArrayList = objectMapper.readValue(handleRESTApiCall(url), new TypeReference<ArrayList<CurrencyList>>() {
        });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return currencyListArrayList;
}

public String handleRESTApiCall(URL url) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String jsonOutput = bufferedReader.readLine();

        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        return jsonOutput;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

You can now test, using `Mockito` on a `URL` instance, the `handleRESTApiCall` without the need for a server instance. The cons are the need to add additional boiler plating on the output of the `handleRESTApiCall` in order to get the object you wish to verify. However, you will benefit from having a basic recurring solution for handling REST api calls in your code.

Refrences:

- [How to mock a web server for unit testing in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606352/how-to-mock-a-web-server-for-unit-testing-in-java)
- [Testable code best practices](https://www.toptal.com/qa/how-to-write-testable-code-and-why-it-matters)